# Как добавить одну наносекунду к переменной типа timestamp?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Я пытаюсь добавить одну наносекунду к переменной типа `timestamp`, но безуспешно.

Вот пример кода:

```
DECLARE
    nextTimestamp TIMESTAMP := TO_TIMESTAMP('11-11-2020 22:10:10.111111111'); 
BEGIN
    nextTimestamp := nextTimestamp + 1 / (10000000*60*60*24);
END;
```

Есть идеи, как можно это сделать?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to add one nanosecond to a timestamp in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19866409) от участника [@Winter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/610093/winter)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/19866409

Comment: А тип в котором хранится timestamp точно позволяет такю гранулярность? А.. вижу вы в ответе тоже это упомянули )

Comment: @Kromster, [тип `TIMESTAMP` позволяет хранить 9 знаков после запятой](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/18.1/sqlfornosql/timestamp.html#GUID-D4BB933E-EC40-476F-97C3-176A34B08CC8) - это как-раз наносекунды

Comment: @Kromster Да ^^^. Выделил в ответе, чтобы заметней было.

Answer (score 4):

Литерал `interval day to second` можно использовать для добавления дробных секунд к значению `timestamp`.

В этом примере добавляем одну наносекунду:

```
select timestamp '2020-11-11 22:10:10.111111111' + 
       interval '0 00:00:00.000000001' day to second (9) as res
from dual
/
RES
-----------------------------
2020-11-11 22:10:10,111111112
```

**На заметку**: Когда используется функция `to_timestamp()`, то надо указать маску формата, а не полагаться на настройки NLS:

```
select 
    to_timestamp ('11-11-2020 22:10:10:111111111', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss:ff9') + 
    interval '0 00:00:00.000000001' day to second (9) as res
from dual
```

**Надо учесть**: Поскольку обработка предполагается в PL/SQL, то надо учесть следующее: по умолчанию точность дробных секунд для значений типа данных `timestamp` в PL/SQL равна 6, а не 9, как в SQL. Поэтому, можно ожидать усечения дробных секунд. Чтобы избежать этого, используйте типы данных `timestamp_unconstrained` и `dsinterval_unconstrained` вместо `timestamp` и `interval day to second`:

```
declare
    ts timestamp_unconstrained := 
        to_timestamp ('11-11-2020 22:10:10:111111111', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss:ff9');
    ns dsinterval_unconstrained := interval '0.000000001' second;
begin
    ts := ts + ns;
    dbms_output.put_line (to_char(ts, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss:ff9'));
end;
/
```

> 11-11-2020 22:10:10:111111112

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19866600) от участника [@Nick Krasnov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997660/nick-krasnov)</sub>